# addEventListener returning null on second invocation

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm trying to create an event that upon clicking, does such and such. I've been successful with doing this once, but the second time it fails. Here is my code:

```
 //Works
 var runButton = document.getElementById('run-button');
 runButton.addEventListener('click', doWork, false);

 //Doesn't work
 var changBeatButton = document.getElementById('changebeat-button');
 changBeatButton.addEventListener('click', changeBeat, false);
```

The error I'm getting in Chrome's debugger is:

[image]

Comment: can you post the error in your question itself?

Comment: Sounds like your selector is not working. Are you sure the second selector is an id and not a class?

Comment: Please check u r HTML.. or pls post fiddle here...

Comment: I don't believe there's an error. I formed it the same way as the previous element. Here's a picture of my html: http://prntscr.com/a82b0a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was pointed out to me that perhaps the event was initiating before the DOM loaded, as such I used window.onload=function(), to make sure everything loaded before I tried to touch anything. This worked!

No idea why the first event would work, but the second wouldn't. Very strange.